# AL5873QT16E-13 LED driver

Tags: led-driver, led-strip

I have a requirement wherein strings of LEDs need to be driven with a maximum forward current of 250 mA, and the dimming should be analog, not PWM.

I have chosen AL5873QT16E-13 which has 3 channels that can independently regulate up to 250 mA each. If I have 5 V as Vin can I only connect 1 LED with a 3.3 V forward drop or more than one LED in series?

How does it regulate current? The datasheet says current ratio blocks, can anyone explain in detail what's going on?

[AL5873QT16E-13](https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/Diodes-Incorporated/AL5873QT16E-13?qs=%2Fha2pyFadui%252BChtJDv7O7kGgBVci5KlMt8mHjkFkpb4%3D)

[Datasheet](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/115/DIOD_S_A0012188447_1-2543710.pdf)

Comment: That is a linear regulator.  It functions like a resistor, dissipating excess voltage to regulate current.  If you have 5v then you are limited to a single series LED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AL5873Q is a simple linear LED driver. This means that the current regulation is done linearly, i.e. any voltage drop is simply turned into heat.

The datasheet does not contain much details about the exact circuitry involved, but you can count on that in the end, there is an N-channel MOSFET connected between each LEDx pin to ground, which does the constant current control together with some current measurement circuitry etc.

As this is a simple low side linear driver, you must supply the LED's with sufficient voltage (the total forward voltage for all series connected LEDs, plus margin for some dropout in the driver). With only 5V supply and a 3.3V LED, sure enough only one LED can be used in series.

Comment: Just what I thought, I had my reservation when I saw 'Linear' and no inductive components in the datasheet, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Can you take a look at this question too?https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/597207/lt3965-octal-bypass-switch