# LT3965 Octal Bypass Switch

Tags: led, led-strip

I have 10 strings of LEDs, string 1 to string 6 have 4 LEDs in series, S7 and S8 have 3 LEDs in series, and S9, S10 have 6 LEDs in series. Each LED has a forward voltage of 3.2 V on average.

I'm going to use a constant current driver that will drive these strings one at a time at a rated current of 250 mA, so I need an IC that can control the strings.

My first thought was to use a demux or multi-channel SPST analog switches with SPI or I2C, but now, in hindsight, I realize I should have gone with FET load switches.

I have chosen the LT3965 and have attached a high-level schematic. Please let me know if this is feasible.

[Datasheet](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/609/LT3965_3965_1-1716272.pdf)

[CC Boost driver](https://www.digikey.in/en/products/detail/leddynamics-inc/4015-D-E-350/1927392)

[Schematic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17cAcQBPydABG0yWY8vc4hKdljNQXOswo/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

The idea and the application looks applicable. But feasibility depends on the outcome versus complexity and cost requirements. If you can say "This will cost me xx $$$ but it is worth to build that circuit to drive these LED strings." then it's feasible. To me, there's a chance to use discrete MOSFETs driven by the MCU. It'd be a bit cheaper but more complex, though.

---

Apart from feasibility, there's one thing you should consider: The risk of breaking some of the LEDs or even the whole strings during switching. Here's why:

If a constant-current booster driver operates unloaded (i.e. no LEDs are attached) then the output voltage rises quickly (up to infinity, theoretically) until it's limited internally by the controller. For the driver you have chosen, it's 48V.

During switching the strings, if the LT3965 operates as a break-before-make switch (highly likely), the output voltage of the LED driver will jump to 48V when one string is detached from the output, and it'll stay at 48V until another string is attached to the output by the LT3965. Because the driver will operate unloaded during this time.

Here's the danger: If the newly attached string is a 3-LED one, the driver's 48V-charged output capacitors will discharge to these LEDs, and thus each LED will see 16V for a short time and this will lead to high current which might be harmful for the LEDs. There's no guarantee that the LEDs will survive.

Comment: Your concern is genuine, but if you look at the datasheet you can see some clamping diodes on individual FETs and on Vin. This will work even if the driver is of buck-boost topology, also I have considered ST's https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l9026.pdf IC load switch intended for inductive load too