# LED string control

Tags: led, led-driver

I have 10 strings of LEDs, string 1 to string 6 have 4 LEDs in series, S7 and S8 have 3 LEDs in series, and S9, S10 have 6 LEDs in series. Each LED has a forward voltage of 3.2 V on average.

I'm going to use a constant current driver that will drive these strings one at a time at a rated current of 250 mA, so I need an IC that can control the strings.

I have chosen a CC LED driver and MAX4656ETA+T SPST switch and have attached a high-level schematic. Please let me know if this is feasible.
**Error in schematic the COM is connected to V- not V+.**

[SPST Switch](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/256/MAX4655-MAX4658-1515602.pdf)

[CC Driver](https://leddynamics.com/boostpuck-4015)

[High Level Schematic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Eb7kr_efxJDoD8OxOR7JdK1l872CjPiP/view?usp=sharing)[image]

**[I have other implementations with different parts, please consider sharing your opinion on that too](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/597207/lt3965-octal-bypass-switch)**

Comment: In your "high level schematic" you appear to switch the LED cathodes to V+? That should be ground. And why not use a simple transistor or logic level FET to do the switching?

Comment: Not everyone can access file storage sites (blocked by wonderful IT), if you post your schematic into the question, then more people can respond.

Comment: @Unimportant Sorry I made a trivial mistake, edited the question. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Aaron i' ll add an image.

Comment: Why not use small MOSFETs as switches? That would be cheaper than the MAX chip...

Comment: @bobflux if I use just discrete Fet's then I need a FET driver since the max voltage 48V probably needs a MOSFET driver and since the CC driver has an inductor in it I need to manage inductive kickback clamping, all these can be managed with one IC with a smaller footprint. like this one https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/mosfet-drivers-controllers/MAX14912.html

Comment: You don't need a FET driver for slow switching on the low side, as shown in the schematic. Also this chip specs a max VCC of 36V, not 48V.

Comment: @bobflux my requirement is just 6 LED's at max so the output is not going to go above 24V

Comment: @bobflux I'm not planning on using this method anyway its too pricey,  I have considered designs like this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/597207/lt3965-octal-bypass-switch

Comment: The boostpuck doesn't specify its maximum unloaded output voltage, so who knows what it is, but if it is the mentioned "48V" in the datasheet, then when the LEDs are off, output voltage will rise to 48V...

Comment: Also I have no idea what you want to do: in one question you mention analog dimming, but what is the range of current for this dimming? Or is it PWM dimming? If so, what frequency? etc

Comment: @bobflux ya, if you look at https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/609/LT3965_3965_1-1716272.pdf they have added clamping diodes to mitigate this

Comment: @bobflux analog dimming is when you supply a reference voltage from a DAC of an MCU to the boost puck control you get a corresponding current. In PWM the duty cycle is varied and the average current varies but the instantaneous current keeps changing but in analog its constant.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea doesn't seem bad just odd. Yes you could use multiple of those switches to switch the common cathode but you may be better off looking for an IC that has multiple switches in one.

The biggest issue is that you Constant Current boost led driver is designed for 350 mA and can only trim between 75% to 120% (if you get the model with the on board trim). That's 265mA on the low end, which is above your 250mA target.

Comment: The problem is you don't have IC's that are multichannel, rated for 300mA continuous current or the rated voltage is less than what is required. Initial stages I was fixated on Analog Demux and Multichannel SPST switches but after I realized this is not panning out I researched and found a few load switch parts that do the job, like https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/609/LT3965_3965_1-1716272.pdf from Linear that is tailored for my requirement and also I have considered ST's st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l9026.pdf IC load switch intended for inductive load too.

Comment: I have made a BOM comparison too, I had considered using 3 channel 14 linear buck CC drivers that cost 1.46$ too, plus these LEDs are in a circular array so I have considered Boost cc driver for ease of routing. You can find that approach in the following post I made https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/597207/lt3965-octal-bypass-switch

Comment: The 75% to 120% limitation is only there if you use the onboard trimmer, page 2 figure 2 shows the graph of Output Voltage vs. Output current, the current can be varied linearly when the control voltage is beyond 1.7V roughly.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/597207/lt3965-octal-bypass-switch https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/597194/al5873qt16e-13-led-driver please have look at this too